# Azure CLI task inline script for a single command on multiple lines for visibility

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

As the title said, I'm looking for a way to display a single command in an Azure CLI inline script on multiple lines.
It is purely for visibility since I happen to have a lot of parameters for the script I'm using.

It is working fine as is but just wondering if it can be improved for future developers.

---

I am aware that adding a pipe "`|`" at the start is used to have multiple lines like this :

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    ## other info
    inlineScript: |
      cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)/scripts/apimdevportal/
      node .\migrate.js --sourceSubscriptionId ${{ parameters.apimSourceSubscriptionId }} --sourceResourceGroupName ${{ parameters.apimSourceRgName }} --sourceEnvironmentName ${{ parameters.apimSourceRgName }} --theListGoesOn
```

The issue, if I may say, is the fact that my `migrate.js` script needs a lot of parameters and I wanted to see them all in one go instead of scrolling horizontally to see the last parameter.

What I want to achieve :

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    ## other info
    inlineScript: |
      cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)/scripts/apimdevportal/
      node .\migrate.js --sourceSubscriptionId ${{ parameters.apimSourceSubscriptionId }} 
                        --sourceResourceGroupName ${{ parameters.apimSourceRgName }} 
                        --sourceEnvironmentName ${{ parameters.apimSourceRgName }} 
                        --theListGoesOn
```

I though of using `|`, `^`, `~` at the end of each line but my pipeline always returns an error.

Again, it is only for a better visibility for the developer.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ` e.g.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    ## other info
    inlineScript: |
      cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)/scripts/apimdevportal/
      node .\migrate.js --sourceSubscriptionId ${{ parameters.apimSourceSubscriptionId }} `
                        --sourceResourceGroupName ${{ parameters.apimSourceRgName }} `
                        --sourceEnvironmentName ${{ parameters.apimSourceRgName }} `
                        --theListGoesOn
```